# Use PHP file_get_contents for IP adress

Tags: php, ip, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents` to retrieve information from a second webserver. I'm using the following code:

```
$json_url ="http://example.com/thisworks.html";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$links = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

But to connect to my webserver i'm using an ip adress with a port, but the following code (file_get_contents with IPadress) doesn't work:

```
$json_url ="44.44.44:5000";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$links = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

(44.44.44 is of course an example)

**UPDATE 1:**

I'm Getting the error:

```
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Just simply adding http:// doesn't work

**UPDATE 3:**

`http://44.44.44` works but `http://44.44.44:5000` doesn't (and i need to use the :5000 port in the url because of the program i use)

Is there a way to use `file_get_contents` this way? Or is it only possible to use it with http:// or https://?

Comment: Try adding `http://` in front of the ip address

Comment: Does not work, it hangs on the :5000 addition

Comment: use curl instead of file_get_contents <= it use port 80

Comment: Yes, but i'm not using port 80, but 5000

Comment: 44.44.44 is not a valid IP address.  Unless that's something you put in your hosts file it's never going to work

Comment: 44.44.44 is just an example (as i said) for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Protocol is required.

From php documentation about protocol wrappers http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php:

> Note: The URL syntax used to describe a wrapper only supports the scheme://... syntax. The scheme:/ and scheme: syntaxes are not supported.

UPD. Also you can register you own protocol http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-wrapper-register.php

UPD 2
If host not works after adding protocol, look at accessability of ip address via network